# Live streaming from iOS to YouTube

Tags: ios, youtube, streaming

According to [these docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/live/) it's pretty easy to start a YouTube live stream from an Android mobile device, deep linking to YouTube Mobile Live.

Does anyone know if there's a similar module available for iOS, or do I have to use the [YouTube Live Streaming API directly](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started)?

Any info is welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, at the time of writing, there is no official YouTube iOS SDK for live streaming and you have to use the API's: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started

There are open source libraries to help with this, however - the one below, for example, is up to date and appears to have received good feedback:

> YTLiveStreaming is a framework for creating live broadcasts and video streams on YouTube using the YouTube Live Streaming API (YouTube Data API v3) in Swift 4

- https://github.com/SKrotkih/YTLiveStreaming

Comment: Thanks a lot Mick! I was looking towards ReplayKit, but this way can be easier.

Comment: Hi @RobinBobin, did you solved your problem? I'm also looking for a good solution.

Comment: Hi @Prashant Gaikwad. No, I'm afraid not. And then it became irrelevant for me.